# Trouble getting AJAX response data with multiple simultaneous jQuery requests when using babel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, babeljs

In my application, I send several simultaneous AJAX `post` requests using jQuery 2.2.2, and build a "master" promise that resolves when all requests are done, like so:

```
let promises = []
//items is 1 or more in length
_.forEach(items, (item) => {
  promises.push(
    $.ajax({
      url: 'some url',
      method: 'post',
      data: item
    })
  )
})

let masterPromise = $.when.apply($, promises)

masterPromise.done(() => {
  let result = []
  let json
  if (promises.length === 1) {
    json = arguments[0]
    //do something with json        
  } else {
    $.each(arguments, function (index, responseData) {
      json = responseData[0]
      result.push(json)
    })
    //do something with result: an array of json responses
  }
})

return masterPromise
```

There are a couple of issues here:

- When using the `function() {}` notation for the callback function the script works fine
- When using the `() => {}` notation,  `arguments` in the callback never contains the actual response data from the requests. It contains an array of the **sent** data from the headers (my `item` variable)

What is the proper way of doing this and why can't I get my response data in the callback?
Thanks!

PS: I'm testing on Chrome 55.0.2883.95 on macOS

**EDIT: after investigating some more, I can get the proper response data from the callback arguments if I write them like this:**

```
masterPromise.done((arg1, arg2) => { /*arg1 and arg2 are the two first ajax requests, but arguments is the sent data*/ })
```

**but I can't get them with `arguments`. I use babel-browser as transpiler and I now suspect it might be related to this.**

***EDIT2: I modified my question slightly because I identified the problem being with the `() => {}` notation in the callback, and the transpiling with babel`.***

Comment: I think `$.when.apply($, promises)` should be `$.when.apply($.when, promises)`

Comment: @JonathanGray - no, it's the former

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right, for some reason in my mind I was reading `.apply` as the method that was being called (it's `.when` of course). I don't know why I thought that since I knew what `.apply` was doing. Brainfart. I think need more sleep. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using arrow function here:

```
.done(() => {
  // ...
})
```

which doesn't populate [`arguments` object](http://No_binding_of_arguments). If you really want to use it (which you probably should not) then use normal function:

```
.done(function() {
  console.log(arguments.length)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out by myself a few minutes ago and edited my question, but you confirm my fears. I can't use the arrow notation here. So the problem doesn't come from babel but from the arrow notation. For some reason I thought they were equivalent (except for the binding of `this` when using an arrow function)

Comment: You also don't need arrow function there, normal function is perfect here too. On the other hand I would not use arguments either. Rest parameters would work for you.

Comment: Yeah I used the arrow function because I otherwise need to bind "this" (not shown in my example) and because I'm lazy. How would you proceed to not use the arguments variable?

Comment: if you're using babel anyway ... `masterPromise.done((...args) => {` then `$.each(args, etc`

Comment: I didn't se you using this so I assumed you don't need arrow function. Otherwise of course. Use rest params see comment above.

Comment: Thank y'all, perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

As you are using babel transpiler, you should be able to use rest parameter syntax `(...args) => {}` - and overall, using babel you should be able to simplify your code as

```
let promises = items.map((item) =>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        method: 'post',
        data: item
    })
);

let masterPromise = $.when.apply($, promises);

masterPromise.done((...args) => {
    let result;
    let json;
    if (args.length === 1) {
        json = args[0]; // shouldn't this be args[0][0] ?
        //do something with json        
    } else {
        result = args.map(responseData => responseData[0]);
        //do something with result: an array of json responses
    }
});
return masterPromise;
```